# Spool of thread velocity direction

Tags: classical-mechanics

So I was thinking about a demonstration our teacher gave us in physics class. He had a spool of thread where the thread was on the downside of the spool, so he asked us questions before pulling on the thread horizontally, he asked us to guess which direction the spool would go. My thought was, since he is pulling on the thread, he is applying a force in that direction (towards himself), the torque from the center of mass would make the spool rotate clockwise(?) but there is also a frictional force which keeps it from slipping and the force from that spool would make the spool rotate anti clockwise and this is what causes it to move towards us? Was my thought. And I seemed to be right

But then he angled the thread from whom he was pulling and asked us again. I guessed the same thing would happen, but at a certain angle it did not roll at all, it just got dragged across the floor and with an angle steep enough it started to move backwards, why is that? It all seems pretty counter intuitive for me. I can't seem to get my head around this. Is it cause when we drag on the thread with an angle then the gravitational effect on the spool would decrease? Since we're getting a force component which is opposite of the gravitational force and the normal force would decrease as well which means that the frictional force gets less and starts to slide instead of rolling?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we are looking along the axis of symmetry of the spool of radius R which is on a horizontal surface with static friction f, and the thread is being pulled to the upper right from a lower inner radius r at an angle of θ degrees from the horizontal, then the horizontal force equation becomes Fcos(θ) – f = ma.  The clockwise torque equation is fR – Fr = Iα.
If the spool is rolling to the right, the a = Rα.  Solving the first equation for f and putting it in the second gives (Fcos(θ) – ma)R - Fr = I(a/R) or  F(Rcos(θ) - r) = (mR + I/R) a.  This assumes that F is not large enough to turn the static friction into kinetic.  For positive acceleration (rolling to the right), R cos(θ) must be larger than r. Otherwise the spool does not rotate or rolls to the left.